# CLLocationManagerDelegate delegate not called iOS in 8.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, location, static-libraries, cllocationmanager

I'm working with CLLocationManagerDelegate in my static library when i run on iOS 7 device everything works perfectly but when i test it on another device with iOS 8.1.3 the delegate methods aren't getting called.
i made a strong property 
**@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager***
i've also added the appropriate key and string value ***(NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription, requestAlwaysAuthorization)*** in the *info.plist*
and this is my instance

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[self.locationManager setDelegate:self];
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; 
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];

if([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
}
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

please help me to find out why delegate methods are not getting called !!
why I'm not getting location updates??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i hope its helps you. Call `[locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]`  inside `if().....`

```
if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
{
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
    {
        [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
else{

    UIAlertView *servicesDisabledAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location Services Disabled" message:@"You currently have all location services for this device disabled. If you proceed, you will be showing past informations. To enable, Settings->Location->location services->on" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:@"Continue",nil];
    [servicesDisabledAlert show];
    [servicesDisabledAlert setDelegate:self];
}


- (void)requestWhenInUseAuthorization
{
CLAuthorizationStatus status = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];

// If the status is denied or only granted for when in use, display an alert
if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse || status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
    NSString *title;
    title = (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) ? @"Location services are off" : @"Background location is not enabled";
    NSString *message = @"To use background location you must turn on 'Always' in the Location Services Settings";

    UIAlertView *alertViews = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                        message:message
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"Settings", nil];
    [alertViews show];
}
// The user has not enabled any location services. Request background authorization.
else if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
    [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}
}


if ([alertView.message isEqualToString:@"To use background location you must turn on 'Always' in the Location Services Settings"])
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        // Send the user to the Settings for this app
        NSURL *settingsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:settingsURL];
    }
}
```

You **MUST** add 
**NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription**  or **NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription** in your Plist file with some message "Your location is needed for this app"

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

CLLocation *location;
location =  [manager location];
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];;

globalObjects.longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",coordinate.longitude];
globalObjects.latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",coordinate.latitude];
}
```

Comment: are you change the code from `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` to yours `requestAlwaysAuthorization`

Comment: mark BreakPoint in `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation`  delegate is this called by `[locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];`

Comment: Nothing happen at all cause the delegate methods isn't getting call at all

Comment: just declare in interface `CLLocationManager  *locationManager;`

Comment: in .h file `@property (nonatomic, retain)CLLocationManager               *locationManager;` or in .m file interface `CLLocationManager *locationManager;`

Comment: in the first time i put it in the .m and now im testing it in the .h  i've put the two type of declaration @proprety and the other in the interface

Answer (score 2):

For iOS 8 you need to define the "Privacy - Location Usage Description" in the Info.plist.

Eg. Privacy - Location Usage Description = "Use your location to show near by stores".

This key specifies the reason for accessing the user’s location information.

Comment: This helped med. The key in question is `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`.

Answer (score 1):

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

[locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
[locationManager setDistanceFilter:5];
[locationManager setHeadingFilter:5];
[locationManager setDelegate:self];

if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
    [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Comment: This will  call all the delegate methods of CLLocationManager.

Answer (score 0):

Can you see something like the following message in your console output?

```
Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization. Must call -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization] first.
```

I ran into this issue when i ported my apps to iOS8 the first time. There is a new restriction for having the following keys defined.

```
    /* Localized versions of Info.plist keys */

"NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" = "for some reason, your app will use your location whenever the app is in foreground";

"NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" = "for some reason, your app will use your location whenever the app is in background";
```

These keys have to be defined in a localizable strings file called **InfoPlist.strings** in your project root directory. I placed this file on the wrong position once, which took me a long time to figure out, where the problem was.

The next thing is, that you should check, that the **life time of your CLLocationManager**, that you have requested the authorization for, has not exceeded when the user's acknowledgement should be processed. E.g. define a global CLLocationManager in your AppDelegate.

I hope that helps,
kind regards,
Peter

Comment: thank you peter for your answer but i dont get any error message in my console :/ i 've added this keys in the plist and also the CLLocation in the appDelegate but i always have a null value of CLLocationManager and never get a location ..

Answer (score 0):

```
if (![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
    {
        [[UtilityClass sharedObject]showAlertWithTitle:@"Location Services disabled" andMessage:@"App requires location services to find your current city weather.Please enable location services in Settings."];
    }
    else{
        [self stopLocationUpdating];
        if (locationManager==nil) {
            locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
            locationManager.delegate = self;
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

            #ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
            if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8"))
            {
                // Use one or the other, not both. Depending on what you put in info.plist
                //[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
                [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
            }
            #endif
        }
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];



        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
```

and add below code into your .plist file

```
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription=Application would like to use your location
```